# How can I construct 100 portfolios with conditional variables in R?

Tags: r, conditional-formatting, finance, portfolio, categorization

I am new with R. I've been trying to construct 100 different portfolios based on market cap for each month. For example, for Mar 1957, I would like to construct 100 portfolios. Portfolio 1 will contain stocks with smallest market cap.

```
head(Portfolios)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups:   Date [1]
  Date      permno    retx retadj.1mn    ME port.weight DateYear
  <yearmon> <fct>    <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Mar 1957  15771  -0.103     -0.103  0.616       0.687     1957
2 Mar 1957  12351   0.586      0.586  1.15        0.725     1957
3 Mar 1957  22963  -0.167     -0.167  0.694       0.833     1957
4 Mar 1957  14461  -0.0638    -0.0638 1.42        1.52      1957
5 Mar 1957  16299   0          0      1.53        1.53      1957
6 Mar 1957  15739  -0.0625    -0.0625 1.46        1.55      1957
```

I tried to use the cut() function but it didn't work. I used the following code:

```
by(Portfolios, Portfolios$Date, function(x) cut_number(Portfolios$port.weight , 100, label = c(1:100)))
```

But it didn't work. If I use ifelse() there would be 100 conditions and it doesn't seem right. Should I use loops? Can anyone help me? Thanks

Edit: I ran `dput(Portfolios)` and obtain very long result but the last few lines of the results are:

```
2903148:2906727, 2906728:2910307, 2910308:2913893, 2913894:2917481, 
    2917482:2921078, 2921079:2924672, 2924673:2928278, 2928279:2931886, 
    2931887:2935496, 2935497:2939121, 2939122:2942767, 2942768:2946429, 
    2946430:2950102, 2950103:2953783, 2953784:2957487, 2957488:2961198, 
    2961199:2964905, 2964906:2968624, 2968625:2972352), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -694L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Explain better what you want to get (what are the conditions, and on which column they apply). Also, post your data in a way we can run code with, paste the output from `dput(Portfolios)` here.

Comment: I edited the question and my data is a RDS file with 3 millions observations so, when i ran `dput(Portfolios)` , the result is very long

Comment: That's better! As for the data, you can select just a part of your dataset then, something like `dput(Portfolios[1:100,])` (just the first hundred lines)

Comment: The output has too many characters. Is there anyway I can attach it without using the characters quota?